# Convert.FromBase64String error for large file/string

Tags: c#, base64

I am having a `FormatException` when using `Convert.FromBase64String`

I have checked `x.length % 4 == 0`
otherwise I pad accordingly.

I have ensured there are no invalid characters.

The strange thing is that when I copy and paste it back into the immediate window or an external converter everything works fine.

While searching with the above point, I found out that one common cause with this behaviour involved the hidden newline character, `/n`.
In that example when the code tried to parse the value it failed because there was an invalid character. However, by copying to notepad the invisible character was removed and from there it worked properly.
This issue seemed very similar to the above; however, I have verified that my value does not have a hidden line break character.

Can you think of any other reasons copy and pasting would work, but working with the data in the code does not? My thoughts is that there must be another character, or something I am not readily seeing.

For Reference,
The line that produces the issue is:

```
data.Data = Convert.FromBase64String(report.Content.ContentValue);
```

A truncated version of the report.Content.ContentValue's value is `"JVBERi0xLjMNCjEgMCBvYmoNCjw8IA0KL0xlbmd0aCA1MzIzDQovRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZQ0‌​KPj4NCnN0cmVhbQ0KWIXtvQdgHEmWJSYvbcp7f0r1Stfg ... trimmed ... g0KPDwgDQovU2l6ZSAxMDcNCi9JbmZvIDEwNiAwIFINCi9Sb290IDUyIDAgUg0KPj4NCnN0YXJ0eHJlZ‌​g0KMzM2MDU4OQ0KJSVFT0Y="`

any ideas would help, thanks.

**UPDATE**
It also is interesting, if I copy the value in questions (x) to my clipboard, and put the following into the immediate window

```
?x == "JVBERi0xLjMNCjEgMCBvYmoNCjw8IA0KL0xlbmd0aCA1MzIzDQovRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZQ0‌​KPj4NCnN0cmVhbQ0KWIXtvQdgHEmWJSYvbcp7f0r1Stfg ... trimmed ... g0KPDwgDQovU2l6ZSAxMDcNCi9JbmZvIDEwNiAwIFINCi9Sb290IDUyIDAgUg0KPj4NCnN0YXJ0eHJlZ‌​g0KMzM2MDU4OQ0KJSVFT0Y="
```

where the `JVBER...` part is the value of x I copied to my clipboard.

The immediate window returns `FALSE`.

This tells me that the act of copying is is changing the string.

Comment: Show us a code example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: "I have checked x.length % 4 == 0 otherwise I pad accordingly. When I copy and paste it back into the immediate window or an external converter everything works fine." Did you paste a padded or an unpadded string?

Comment: int len = x.Length % 4;
                    if (len > 0)
                        x = x.PadRight(x.Length + (4 - len), '=');


but the length is correct and it doesnt require padding. 
--
I literally break the code, copy the value of x, and paste it into the immediate window and it works.

so like, System.Convert.FromBase64String(x)      doesnt work

copy the result of ?x from my immediate windows then try

System.Convert.FromBase64String(___the value I copied from my immediate window__)

and it works

Comment: No I mean code that reproduces the error in `Convert.FromBase64String`.

Comment: data.Data = Convert.FromBase64String(report.Content.ContentValue);
produces the error


The value of  report.Content.ContentValue   is  "JVBERi0xLjMNCjEgMCBvYmoNCjw8IA0KL0xlbmd0aCA1MzIzDQovRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZQ0KPj4NCnN0cmVhbQ0KWIXtvQdgHEmWJSYvbcp7f0r1Stfg ... trimmed ... g0KPDwgDQovU2l6ZSAxMDcNCi9JbmZvIDEwNiAwIFINCi9Sb290IDUyIDAgUg0KPj4NCnN0YXJ0eHJlZg0KMzM2MDU4OQ0KJSVFT0Y="

Comment: How are you getting the base64 string that you are converting from?

Comment: The file was already encoded within an xml document. There was a media tag with, and this was the content. As I said I am able to copy the content and convert it through other means, but directly it doesnt like the it.

Comment: I would assume programatically you are grabbing something other than what you intend or something in addition to what you intend.  Even if it looks the same the bytes are obviously not the same.  How are you reading the xml & what is the encoding of the xml file?  My recommendation is to write the base64string out to a file and see if it's different from what you copy / paste.

Comment: @CodeMusic Let's do it a clean way. Prepare a simple,self contained, compilable code that shows your case so that we can reproduce it when we only copy,paste and run your code. Read the first comment posted 25 mins ago. Your problem might have been solved by now if you had done this.

Comment: I cant really paste the code to reproduce it when my pasted value works fine. The only way I could do that would be to upload the file which I am not able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above issue appears to be related to a file size issue.

As mentioned above `Convert.FromBase64String(report.Content.ContentValue);` did not initially work; however, by splitting `report.Content.ContentValue` into four smaller sections, adjusting the padding, converting then merging the results into a single data array I am able to produce the expected results.

```
foreach (string partialInput in splitInputArray) 
{                                                 
        string paddedPartialInput = partialInput;
        int lengthAdjustment = partialInput.Length % 4; 

        if (lengthAdjustment > 0) //do we need to fix the padding
            paddedPartialInput = paddedPartialInput.PadRight(paddedPartialInput.Length + (4- lengthAdjustment), '=');                        

        repairedOutput = MergeByteArrays(repairedOutput, Convert.FromBase64String(paddedPartialInput));
}
```

I still do not understand why `Convert.FromBase64String(...)` didnt just work on the full input; however, if you find yourself encountering issue with large files and `Convert.FromBase64String(...)` then you should give this solution a try.