# Extract Base64 String

Tags: c#, xml, regex, encoding, base64

I have a string from an `XML file` that I need to `base64` decode.
However, it looks like there are some *invalid characters* within the string.

I tried writing some code to remove any invalid characters, and then re-pad but it appears that my source data may have some invalid invisible characters within it.

So, I figured the best approach since I know the valid base64 characters is to just have a function to extract all the valid characters, that way every invalid character would be purged.

*Is there an quick way to test this theory?*

My other question was about base64 itself,
after researching it appears that while `A-Z,a-z,0-9` are **62** of the valid base64 characters the rest can depend on file encoding.

*Is it possible my file is using some other base64 scheme?*

When I scanned my file on top of the common `A-Z,a-z,0-9` I have found `=`'s within the files, not just as padding. I tried removing those and repadding, but I still seem to have invalid characters.

This is now more a general question since I am unable to post my base64 encoded string.

---

**Updated question**
This update is about the first part of my original question,

If I have a string of say 1000 random character, and I want to remove every character that is not in a set. Say my set is "A","B",C","D",E","F","G". What would be the easiest (and fast, no loops) way to remove all characters which are not in the set?

Comment: Try with a custom routine to decode base64, at least you'll see where/what is wrong.

Comment: Good Idea. I will give that a try and see where it leads me. Thanks Adriana.

Comment: For updated question: you have to loop through input then fastest way is to simply _do not copy_ characters outside your allowed set. c = a.Where(x => b.Contains(x))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there were not any invalid characters in my file, it looks like it was more specifically a file size issue.

When I split the data into smaller sections, padded, converted, and merged the bytes array together a readable pdf file was produced.

For more details, including the steps I took to resolve this issue / come to this conclusion, see this thread:
[Convert.FromBase64String Strange Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556517/convert-frombase64string-strange-issue/25572086#25572086)

Thanks for the suggestions which lead to this.